# Understanding how to use Turbo with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

I am trying to understand how to use Turbo in order to refresh the content of the page without having to refresh the page.  I have gone through some videos and web tutorials, but it doesn't apply to the way I have my page setup, and I am trying to figure out if my setup is poor design and I should change it, or if its possible to add Turbo functionality into my code.  I am new to Ruby on Rails and Turbo so may not have enough understanding for it to click yet.  Essentially, I have a form on my index page that allows the user to select the state and once submitted, show a new select box with cities from that state as well as a list of all the facilities in a state.  Once the user selects a city and submits the form, the list of facilities is limited to just that city.  The form gets submitted back to the index page. I want to update the city select box and table via the facilities partial that displays the facilities on the index page based on the form submission, but from every tutorial I have seen, the form gets submitted to a different function that calls up a new page to replace the current section.  Is there a way to do it from my current code, or do I need to have the form call a different function as well?

index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Facilities") %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <br>
    <%= form_with(url: facilities_path, method: :get, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <table class="table table-borderless">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="form-inline">
              <%= f.label :state_id, "State" %> &nbsp;
              <%= f.collection_select :state_id, @states, :id, :state_long, {:selected => params[:state_id], include_blank: 'Select A State'}, {class: 'form-control'}  %>
            </div>
          </td>

          <% if !params[:state_id].blank? %>
            <td>
              <div class="form-inline">
                <%= f.label :city_id, "City" %> &nbsp;
                <%= f.collection_select :city_id, @cities, :id, :city_titlecase, {:selected => params[:city_id], include_blank: 'Select A City'}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
              </div>
            </td>
          <% end %>

          <td><%= f.submit "Update Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <% if @facilities.any? %>
      <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Facility</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <%= render @facilities %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <span style="float:right"><%= will_paginate %></span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Facilities_Controller.rb

```
  def index
    @states = State.all

    #Get the state id from the database based on the state long name
    current_state_db = State.find_by(state_long: current_state)

    if params[:state_id].blank?
      @facilities = Facility.all.joins(:state, :city).order("states.state_short, cities.city, facility_name").paginate(page: params[:page])
    else
      @cities = City.where(state_id: params[:state_id])

      if params[:city_id].blank?
        @facilities = Facility.where(state_id: params[:state_id]).joins(:state, :city).order("states.state_short, cities.city, facility_name").paginate(page: params[:page])
      else
        #Check to make sure the city_id is in the selected state -> if the user changed the state a city was selected, it would keep the old city in the params
        expected_state = City.find_by(id: params[:city_id]).state_id
        if params[:state_id].to_i == expected_state
          @facilities = Facility.where(state_id: params[:state_id], city_id: params[:city_id]).joins(:state, :city).order("states.state_short, cities.city, facility_name").paginate(page: params[:page])
        else
          #The current selected city is not in the state
          @facilities = Facility.where(state_id: params[:state_id]).joins(:state, :city).order("states.state_short, cities.city, facility_name").paginate(page: params[:page])
        end
      end
    end

  end
```

I have gone through multiple turbo videos and tutorials but they refer to the form calling a different function and view that then replaces the current view with the same turbo id. I am hoping to find a way to do this with the form submitting to the index function.  I am still learning about Turbo and AJAX, but from my understanding of what I have read, Turbo uses AJAX behind the scenes to accomplish this?

Comment: What you're asking is a age old question - when the user updates one select you want to change the available choices in another select. You basically add an event listener to the select that sends an AJAX request to the backend and then you use the response to exchange the options in the in the other select element. This is pretty simple - if you actually have a grasp of the fundamentals like the difference between server and client side, how to send AJAX requests and how to render a JSON response or render a chunk of HTML. But you really need to start from the ground up and learn those first.

Comment: [MDN has a lot of good resources for learning JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started). Turbo can be used for this, and yes it does send AJAX requests as well as use WebSockets. But if you're completly new to this it just adds more layers of abstraction and complexity. There are also a plethora of tutorials (just not necissarily Turbo  or Rails specific) as well countless libraries of varying quality that deal with this issue.

Comment: Thanks @max, you are right, I am totally new at this and need to learn the basic foundations first.  I was able to get the state and city select box to dynamically update using examples of stimulus I found.  I will probably just leave it at that for right now until I get a better understanding of JS and AJAX.  Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you put it in a turbo frame it makes no difference where the form is submitted as long as you respond with the matching frame. Maybe this example is a bit convoluted, but it shows what you can do. It is auto submitting to the same page, controller action is empty, only non obvious thing is that different frame is updated for different fields:

```rb
<%= tag.div data: {controller: "selector"} do %>
  <%= form_with url: "/", data: {selector_target: "form"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :state, State.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true},
      {data: {action: "selector#nextFrame", selector_frame_param: "cities"}} %>

    # ^ this will update v this frame

    <%= turbo_frame_tag :cities do %>
      <% if (current_state = State.find_by(id: params[:state])) %>
        <%= f.collection_select :city, current_state.cities, :id, :name, {prompt: true},
          {data: {action: "selector#nextFrame", selector_frame_param: "facilities"}} %>

        # ^ this will update v this frame

        <%= turbo_frame_tag :facilities do %>
          <% if (current_city = current_state.cities.find_by(id: params[:city])) %>
            Facilities for <%= current_city.name %>
            ...

          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Notice that i'm not setting `selected` option, because fields outside of the target frame don't reset.

Use stimulus to dynamically update frame target and submit the form:

```bash
bin/rails g stimulus selector
```

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/selector_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["form"];
  nextFrame(event) {
    const form = this.formTarget;
    form.dataset.turboFrame = event.params.frame; // load the next frame
    form.requestSubmit();                         // after submitting the form
  }
}
```